# Socket.io connection works locally but not in production serve

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, socket.io

I am trying to establish a WebSocket connection between my Dart client and a Socket.io server running in production, but I am encountering an error in the server logs. Specifically, the client is sending a GET request with the following parameters:

GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket HTTP/1.0 Dart/2.19 (dart:io)

However, the server is responding with a 400 Bad Request error. This issue seems to occur only when I try to connect to the server from a remote location. When I run the client on my local machine, the connection works without any issues. I am using the socket_io_client package to create the Socket.io client in Dart and have configured it to use the websocket transport.

I am unsure what could be causing this error and would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

I have tried several troubleshooting steps, including checking the server logs for any errors, verifying the server URL and port, ensuring that the server is configured to accept WebSocket connections, and checking the client code for any errors or typos.

I expected the Dart client to establish a WebSocket connection with the Socket.io server and receive data in real-time. However, when I try to connect to the server from a remote location, the server responds with a 400 Bad Request error, and the connection fails. This issue seems to occur only in production, as the connection works fine when I run the client on my local machine.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may add the console error here so we can see it.

Comment: it is a bad request try to check the server log .

Answer (score 0):

If the WebSocket connection is being established over SSL, it's possible that there is an issue with the SSL certificate being used by the server.
Try with this :

> Inside main.dart file

before main function add :

```
    class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
      @override
      HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
        return super.createHttpClient(context)
          ..badCertificateCallback =
              (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
      }
    }
```

and inside main function add :

```
HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help earlier! I managed to resolve the issue by disabling nginx and proxy mode on my server, and increasing the size of data in each request to 128 MB. It worked perfectly fine, and I realized that the problem was not related to Flutter or Dart. If I encounter any further issues, I'll make sure to review my code and optimize it.